# How to extract text from web and add into another file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've one shell script where i mentioned as

```
#!/bin/sh
.........
curl -X POST -d text={varX} $WEB_LINK
.............
```

So I want to extract text of **WEB_LINK** and add into another file like **xyz.txt**. Could you please help me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd="curl -X POST -d text={varX} $WEB_LINK > xyz.txt"
bash -c "$cmd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
text=$(curl -s $WEB_LINK)    
echo $text > xyz.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @protob but i want to get clarification earlier i used `curl -X POST -d ....` and then after i am using `curl -s ..` only. So will it execute without any error.